# Simulation of oscillator with frequency dependent damping

Tags: classical-mechanics, mathematical-physics, harmonic-oscillator, simulations, oscillators

What would be the equation for the frequency dependent damping of harmonic oscillator? Is there something like:

$$
\ddot{x}+2\delta\dot{x}+\omega_0^2x = \frac{F}{m}f(t)
$$

with frequency dependent damping?
Of course, it could be done by stating $\delta=\delta(\omega)$, but

- is there an example from mathematical physics where something like this arises from equation of motion?
- what is the physics behind?

*Note 1: This question is motivated by sound synthesis task, but I am looking for physical backround. Therefore it's not engineering nor computational science.*

Comment: This is the equation for forced vibration. It has solutions in the following link......http://www.brown.edu/Departments/Engineering/Courses/En4/Notes/vibrations_forced/vibrations_forced.htm and https://people.math.osu.edu/kwa.1/wi11notes/3.9we.pdf .... Do you want to know anything different? Please specify.

Comment: Yes, of course, that's pretty simple equation. I am looking for making it more general by addition of frequency dependent damping.

Comment: @Victor Pira did you find any answer to this question. I am searching for the same example.

Answer (score -1):

Functionally the solution does not change.  You can still use phasors to write the equation as[image]

goes to

[image]

Where X is the fourier image of x and F is the fourier image of the driving force f(t).  because [image] does not depend on time, its fourier image does not change.  The solution is
[image]